# SQL calculation of subquery data

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm confused on a calculation I'm trying to make using a subquery.  I have 2 subqueries created, o & p, and am creating a query to hit data from those subqueries.

WITH
o AS (SELECT productCode, sum(quantityOrdered) as quantity_ordered
FROM orderdetails
GROUP BY productCode),

p AS (SELECT productCode, quantityInStock
FROM products)

SELECT p.productCode, p.quantityInStock, o.quantity_ordered, o.quantity_ordered/p.quantityInStock AS demand
FROM p
JOIN o
ON p.productCode=o.productCode

The resulting query correctly pulls in the quantity in stock and quantity ordered, but the calculation fails and shows up as 0.  I'm not sure why this would be?

product     instock ordered %

S10_1678    7933    1057    0

S10_1949    7305    961     0

S10_2016    6625    999     0

S10_4698    5582    985     0

S10_4757    3252    1030    0

S10_4962    6791    932     0

Answer (score 1):

The columns in the division (o.quantity_ordered/p.quantityInStock) are integers, you need to cast these as a DECIMAL or FLOAT data type. For example:

```sql
WITH o AS (SELECT productCode, sum(quantityOrdered) as quantity_ordered FROM orderdetails GROUP BY productCode),

p AS (SELECT productCode, quantityInStock FROM products)

SELECT p.productCode, p.quantityInStock, o.quantity_ordered, CAST(o.quantity_ordered AS DECIMAL)/CAST(p.quantityInStock AS DECIMAL) AS demand FROM p JOIN o ON p.productCode=o.productCode
```